# lock/Monitor with multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, monitor

In .NET, suppose `thread A` locks an object. Meanwhile, `thread B` and `thread C` are blocked and wait for the object to be unlocked by `thread A`.

Now, `thread A` unlocked the object. which of the threads (B or C) will be chosen next? how is it determined?

Comment: You can not determine which of the threads will be chosen. Moreover, sometimes the system might choose thread B and on other times it will be thread C.

Comment: Still, system performance will depend on how the system chooses. Threads may starve if it continually favors one over the other.

Comment: @flup - if designed well, this should not happen.  Threads that are 'starved' will get blocked and so free up CPU for those that can make progress.  That's kinda the whole point.

Comment: @MartinJames Exactly! So the question is what this design is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it is non-deterministic - i.e. you never know.

The medium answer is that threads waiting to acquire a lock are put in the "ready queue", which is FIFO, but you can't rely on that.

The long answer is that threads in the ready queue can be "borrowed" to run small pieces of work called APCs ( [`Asynchronous Procedure Calls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) When this happens, they lose their place in the queue and when the APC is finished, they are put back in the ready queue - but at the end.

So, back to the short answer: you never know.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the first one that tried to get the lock (like a queue), [See more here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/threading-with-monitor-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Assuming they have the same priority? Or always?

Comment: I think it's always the same, Thread priorities is implemented in the kernel, It is only changes the way that the "Thread scheduler" prioritise time slots for each thread (As far as I know)